# python key input logic using msvcrt

Tags: python, msvcrt

I need to do roughly the following:

```
while True:
    if *a key is pressed within 5 seconds of some prior event*:
        print(*the specific key that was pressed)
    elif *5 seconds pass with no key press*
        print("No key pressed")
```

I posted about my specific needs in another question ([Read specific key with msvcrt.getch() OR move on after set time with no input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76893525/read-specific-key-with-msvcrt-getch-or-move-on-after-set-time-with-no-input)), but I figure this format is much more approachable. The critical part here is that I must know what key was pressed. I have been trying to use `msvcrt.getch() amd msvcrt.kbhit()`, but it seems I need some sort of hybrid.

Can anyone figure this out?

Windows 11, Python 3.11.0

Comment: Could you use the `keyboard` library? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/keyboard-module-in-python/

Comment: I've tried but haven't figured out anything that works